# Netsuite rest api using OAuth 2.0 Authorization code grant type refresh token validity (Expiration)

Tags: netsuite, netsuite-rest-api

Netsuite rest api using OAuth 2.0 Authorization code grant type refresh token validity (Expiration).
In how many days we need to perform OAuth dance again?

[netsuite](/questions/tagged/netsuite) [tag:netsuite rest api]
#netsuite

Please ans the above question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.